# Quantization of Chiral Boson

Tags: quantization, quantum-hall-effect, chern-simons-theory

I am trying to understand the edge modes of fractional quantum Hall(FQH) effect from ChernSmions theory picture. Chern-Simons action with a boundary along $y$ produces the following  action

> $ \mathcal{L} =-\frac{m}{4\pi}\intop\left\{ \partial_{x}\phi\partial_{t}\phi+c\left(\partial_{x}\phi\right)^{2}\right\} \,dx$

Where $\frac{1}{m}$ is the filling fraction of bulk FQH and $c$ is the non-universal velocity of the edge states. I was trying to quantize this action using the periodic boundary condition of $\phi$ as follows

$\varphi\left(x+L,t\right)\equiv\varphi\left(x,t\right)$

$\varphi\left(x,t\right)=\sum_{n}e^{\iota\frac{2\pi nx}
{L}}\varphi_{n}\left(t\right)$

$\varphi_{n}\left(t\right)=\frac{1}{L}\intop_{0}^{L}dx\:e^{-\iota\frac{2\pi nx}{L}}\varphi\left(x,t\right)$

$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{m}{2}\sum_{\overset{n\neq0}{n\in\mathbb{Z}}}\left\{ \left(\iota n\varphi_{n}\dot{\varphi}_{-n}\right)+c\left(\frac{2\pi}{L}\right)\left(n^{2}\varphi_{n}\varphi_{-n}\right)\right\} $

$\pi_{p}=\frac{m}{2}\left(\iota p\varphi_{-p}\right)$

$H=\sum_{p}\pi_{p}\dot{\varphi}_{p}-\mathcal{L}$

$H=\frac{4\pi}{mL}c\left[\sum_{n>0}\pi_{n}\pi_{-n}+\sum_{n>0}\left(\frac{mn}{2}\right)^{2}\varphi_{n}\varphi_{-n}\right]$

**Question**
My question is that in this procedure we lost the information about the zero modes of the field $\phi$. I would like to know whether this prescription is right or not.